# React Native Maps: How to render components below the map?

Tags: react-native, flexbox, react-native-maps, react-native-component, react-native-stylesheet

I just implemented [React Native Maps](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps) in my application.

My problem is that everything that I render below the maps is rendered on top of it. Let me show you what I mean:

[image: Searchbar and random texts get rendered above the map.]

My question is how do I avoid my components being rendered on top of the map? I would like for them to be rendered below.

Here is my code:

HomeScreen.js:

```
render() {
    return (
      <SafeContainer>
        <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.container}>
          <MapsContainer />
          <SearchBar icon={require("../../assets/icons/searchingGlass.png")} />
          <Text textID={"homescreen_text"}>This is going to be the HomeScreen</Text>
          <RestaurantList />
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
      </SafeContainer>
    );
  }

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1
  }
});
```

MapsContainer.js:

```
  <View style={styles.mapContainer}>
    <MapView
      style={styles.map}
      initialRegion={{
        latitude: 58.192312,
        longitude: 7.072301,
        latitudeDelta: 0.0145,
        longitudeDelta: 0.0055
      }}
    />
  </View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  mapContainer: {
    position: "absolute",
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    height: imageWidth * (2 / 3),
    backgroundColor: colors.$primaryWhite
  },
  map: {
    position: "absolute",
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out what I was doing wrong. The maps styles I used where completely unnecessary (got them from some github issue while implementing maps for the first time :D).

Here are the styles that I use now:

```
const imageWidth = Dimensions.get("window").width;
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  mapContainer: {
    height: imageWidth * (2 / 3),
    backgroundColor: colors.$primaryWhite
  },
  map: {
    height: imageWidth * (2 / 3)
  }
});
```

Comment: Be careful with using this approach. When the User changes their orientation, it's imperative that you re-calculate the window width.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to place the element `<searchBar/>` or any other element you want under `<view/>` component. To make sure it rendered below the `<MapsContainer/>`, you should set position of `<view/>` to relative and add some margin.

Well, this is my pseudo code of what i mean :

HomeScreen :

```
    render() {
    return (
      <SafeContainer>
        <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.container}>
          <MapsContainer />
          <View style={styles.view1}> //nesting the element
            <SearchBar icon={require("../../assets/icons/searchingGlass.png")} />
            <Text textID={"homescreen_text"}>This is going to be the HomeScreen</Text>
            <RestaurantList />
          <View/>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
      </SafeContainer>
    );
  }

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1
  }
  view1: {
   position: relative, //styling goes here
   marginTop: 10
)}
```

you could give it a try, cheers

Comment: Thank you sincerely for your help, but this did unfortunately not work :(

Comment: In your device, you might need to activate Show Layout Bound menu on your settings --> developer options. You can identify all the element you put on the screen and their size. From that, you can analyzing what things gone wrong.